# Problem upgrading to Debian unstable

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade Debian stable (Stretch, clean install) to unstable:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But I get [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0091f610a7854b38b5210232d71d7029).

I have tried running `apt-get -f install` and `apt-get --fix-broken install`, but this also fails.

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` only has one line:

```
deb http://ftp.dk.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
```

How do I fix this so I can finish the upgrade? Is there an error in my upgrade procedure?

**EDIT:** The problem doesn't seem to arise when I install using the nextinst-image instead of the livecd-image.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I did even though I didn't specify it.

Comment: 1. There is no need to run `apt-get upgrade` before `apt-get dist-upgrade`. There's no harm in doing so, but it's not necessary.  2. `unstable` changes constantly and it is not uncommon for there to be specific moments when unstable upgrades don't complete successfully.  3. This is especially true when part of the upgrade involves significant version changes in multiple related packages (like gnome. or kde). 4. Sometimes the "fix" is to wait until the mirror has updated and then try again. Sometimes there will be one or more packages that need to be manually updated (or held. or removed).

Comment: BTW, I find it best to have sources.list entries for both stable and unstable (and possibly even testing) ,and set the default release in an `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` file.  e.g. `APT::Default-Release "unstable";`.  apt will use whatever you define there as the default package source unless you override with `-t <release>`.

Comment: You can manually remove  the package which block the system upgrade then install them.